# Dynamic text in XML

Tags: android, button, dynamic, textview

So in my Android application, there are many buttons with TextView. They have hardcoded values.  So for large screens, I again have to define the values. So **is there any way I can have dynamic text which adjusts itself with the screen size**? It should always use the same percentage of the button in different screen sizes.  It would be very tiring to individually change values for different screen sizes.

Note : I want a way to do it in XML , not in the java file.

Comment: I suggest let the buttons expand a little rather than having super small text. Also remember to use *sp* when specifying font sizes, so it gets adjusted to smaller screens.

Comment: Did you try using weights?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein How do I use weights for text? Can I get a snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Weights only work in LinearLayouts (and derivates).
They are used to **evenly** distribute **ONE** dimension **in percentage**.
The trick is to set the affected dimension to **0dp** and the weight to **1** (it says: divide EVENLY)

A little example: A horizontal Layout with 2 50% sized TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/text1"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/text2"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

You are supposed to have preared 2 strings in your `/res/values/strings.xml` file:
text1 and text2

If you want to change the proportions, you can change the weights: 40% and 60%?
Just set the weights to (you choose): 40 and 60 or 4 and 6 or 0.4 and 0.6, ...

Obviously, you can use more than 2 Views.

Also obviously, you can set the height **instead** of the width (never together!).

And avoid nesting LinearLayouts to set the weights to both width and heights, because it's bad for performances.

Comment: So if I want to have ONE textview in ONE layout, but I dont want it to cover 100% of the layout, maybe 80%, so would it be alright, if I give the weight as 1? or should I give some decimal?

Comment: No... 0.8 (1 would mean 100%). But it's better if then you set an INVISIBLE TextView to 0.2 as well.